# display condition with css in wordpress website

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a WordPress website and in my website I have two fields for which I want to write a condition with CSS that if the user is logged in, the field will be displayed, otherwise it will not be displayed.
thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for this class in the body tag:

```
.logged-in
```

It's a class Wordpress will add if someone is logged in. Note that not all themes may support this.

Then, use that in your css selector:

```
.logged-in #my-div { display: block } //or whatever display you want
```